# Looking for a book about tattoo magic where a young woman is an apprentice to her uncle

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

Teen girl/young woman is taken on as her uncle's apprentice in the art of magic tattoos and begins learning. Gets her first tattoo. Her uncle's name could have been **Gage**.  Something happens and they (her and the others that work at the tattoo shop?) go on the run or looking for someone.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/series/72722-the-asylum-tales? Guy called Gage is a magical tattoo artist. Can't find anything about his niece being an apprentice though

Comment: It was 5-6 years ago. I'm not certain on the uncle's name. I've been trying to find it off and on for several years with no luck. I remember there being mention of the tattoos glowing when activated, and special ingredients used to make the ink.

Comment: Anything more you can remember would be useful.

Comment: I very specifically remember her uncle being a tattoo artist and her starting her apprenticeship to him in the first 5 chapters

Comment: Reminds me of Ink Mage (A Fire Beneath the Skin series) by Victor Gischler. But that was not about an apprentice. I can't get to the book at the moment, but if I find any more info I'll post later.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [The Keepers' Tattoo](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/7193485), Gill Arbuthnott, 2010?

From a reader review:

> The story starts (after the prologue) with Nyssa being a young woman
> having a relatively normal life except for the fact that she is an
> orphan. She doesn't know her life is in danger. She doesn't know that
> a power crazed man named Alaric wants to find her and use the words
> tattooed on the back of her head. She doesn't know she had a twin
> brother. She doesn't know she is part of an ancient clan that she had
> always believed was a legend nothing more. Now she must run away with
> her uncle from everything she's known-or thought she knew-save her
> life and possibly more.
>
> This is fantasy, however it doesn't have a map. Which is small thing
> but seriously, no map?
>
> I liked that Nyssa wasn't given a love interest just for the sake of
> making things more dramatic. Nyssa is a good protagonist. She is smart
> and assertive. The point of view changes between a few character but
> it's mostly Nyssa.
>
> One thing that I liked throughout the book was the group always
> staying together. **At first it's only Nyssa and her uncle but
> eventually two more members are included later in their hiding
> escapade**.

Comment: I looked at it. But it's not the one. I very specifically remember her uncle being a tattoo artist and her starting her apprenticeship to him in the first 5 chapters.